# permission denied when inserting into table created by HCTAS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, teradata

I am having trouble with Teradata's HCTAS procedure when I use it to create a table in Hadoop.

I call HCTAS to create the table,

```
CALL SYSLIB.HCTAS('test_table',null,null,'myserver','default');
 *** Procedure has been executed.
```

but when I try to insert data into that table, I get a permission denied.

```
INSERT INTO test_table@myserver SELECT * FROM test_table;
 *** Failure 7810 [TblOp] Permission denied: user=myuser, access=WRITE, inod
 e="/apps/hive/warehouse/test_table":hive:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoo
 p.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChec
 ker.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.s.
            Statement# 1, Info =0
```

I checked Hadoop and found that the directory was created with owner as 'hive' instead of 'myuser'.

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hive hdfs          0 2015-08-05 21:45 /apps/hive/warehouse/test_table
```

What should I do so that the directories will be created with 'myuser' as the owner?

Thanks

Comment: Hey @sont,  Could you tell me how you are creating the table "test_table", please. When you create a table you should give the specific location, if you dont give a specific location de location by default is "/hive/warehouse/". Try give a location where you have write permissions.

Comment: Hi @dbustosp, I thought that HCTAS looks at the table in Teradata and creates it on Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter is used to specify the directory, try

```
CALL SYSLIB.HCTAS('test_table',null,'LOCATION "/usr/myuser"','myserver','default');
```

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, do you mean "/user/myuser"?

Comment: @sont: any directory where you got write permission, on Hadoop probably */users/myuser*

Answer (score 0):

As you can see this is a write permissions problem, because myuser does not have permissions to write in /hive/warehouse/.

Oh the other hand, as you can see [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_00/index.html#page/QueryGrid_TD_Hadoop/B035_1185_015K/SQL-H_ch3_tbl_ops.05.23.html), you can specify the location of the table where you are sure that myuser has write permissions (personal folder in the HDFS maybe). In this way you will not have write permissions problems.